# Increase hover area for routes in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes

I display several routes on google maps. When users hovers/clicks over/on the routes (or in their vicinity) I bring up a pop up with route information.

The problem is, I think Google didn't make the routes to be clicked/hovered on because you **need great mouse precision**! You **gotta be on the route pixels** to click on it or hover to activate. That's quite challenging!

I've tried making the route lines thicker, but I can't make them too thick before they overlap and become visually useless.

**How to increase hover area?**

I've noticed that for directions, Google has a mouse tracker that shows up for a larger mouse distance from a route. This mouse tracker is a point on a route which shows up when the mouse is a certain distance from the route. It's kinda what I want. I could implement one manually by going through all the segments in a route and calculate distance from segment end points (and perhaps a few points interpolated on a segment - depending on segment length) to mouse coordinates on map. I'd have to take into account zoom level or have a way to transform distance on map to distance/pixels on screen.